# How can i choose where cell I want to start filling data in my excel report?

Tags: vba, excel

Sir,

How can I choose which cell I want to start filling data in my excel report?

I have this code:

```
  For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                xlSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) =
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry sir, i want to know how  to define a specific cell to start; for example i want to start populate data on cell a9, because in my loop the starting point of cell in excel and the starting point of the datatable is the same. any suggestion sir? sorry for my English.

Comment: If you want to start at A9 instead of A1, just change `xlSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) =` to `xlSheet.Cells(i + 9, j + 1) =`.

Comment: Great. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start at A9 instead of A1, just change `xlSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) =` to `xlSheet.Cells(i + 9, j + 1) =`.